# Python: Compare values of two fields with multiple strings and add all unique values to a 3rd field

Tags: python, pandas, list, compare

I am still a Python-Rookie and are stuck with an idea.
I want to compare the values of Type1 with Type2 and add all unique values to a 3rd field.

My demo data:
[Demo Data Car Types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaZDV.png)

I tried to import it into a Pandas dataframe and loop through it to append the missing values to Type2 (if Type1 not in Type2, Type2.append(Type1)).

I also tried to concatenate both lists and reduce it to unique values by using set().

I get plenty of results, but not what I need. The result should be:
[Demo Data Car Types with results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSJQZ.png)

How would you approach this?

Thank you for your support,
Konstantin

Comment: Please post your data here as text not as figures. Is your DataFrame containing strings or lists?

Answer (score 0):

How is your datas stored ?

If your work with `list` :

```py
Type1 = ["Scirocco", "Golf"]
Type2 = ["Golf", "Polo", "Phaeton"]
Result = set(Type1).union(Type2)  # It is a set not a list
```

If you work with `string` :

```py
Type1 = "Scirocco, Golf"
Type2 = "Golf, Polo, Phaeton"
# Manage your data with list object
l_Type1 = Type1.remove(",").split()  # Create list from values between " "
l_Type2 = Type2.remove(",").split() 
set_Result = set(Type1).union(Type2)
# Create a string from set_Result values separated by ", "
Result = ", ".join(set_Result)
```

Comment: Thank you as well. 'remove' is apparently not working with strings though. But no worries, I have the solution now.

Comment: Then make this issues solved
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix and his counterpart removesuffix are the only "remove" method on string

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

### If the columns store strings:

```
   Marke           Type1                Type2
0     VW  Scirocco, Golf  Golf, Polo, Phaeton
1   Opel  Ascona, Rekord        Kadett, Corsa
2   Ford  Focus, Granada  Taunus, Focus, Kuga
3  Volvo   V40, V70, 240             V90, S80
```

```
df['Result'] = (df['Type1'] + ', ' + df['Type2']).str.split(', ').map(dict.fromkeys).str.join(', ')

print(df)
```

### If the columns store lists:

```
   Marke             Type1                  Type2
0     VW  [Scirocco, Golf]  [Golf, Polo, Phaeton]
1   Opel  [Ascona, Rekord]        [Kadett, Corsa]
2   Ford  [Focus, Granada]  [Taunus, Focus, Kuga]
3  Volvo   [V40, V70, 240]             [V90, S80]
```

```
df['Result'] = (df['Type1'] + df['Type2']).map(dict.fromkeys).str.join(', ')

print(df)
```

Using a `dict` will ensure you will have the keys in order, matching your target result.

### Result:

```
   Marke           Type1                Type2                         Result
0     VW  Scirocco, Golf  Golf, Polo, Phaeton  Scirocco, Golf, Polo, Phaeton
1   Opel  Ascona, Rekord        Kadett, Corsa  Ascona, Rekord, Kadett, Corsa
2   Ford  Focus, Granada  Taunus, Focus, Kuga   Focus, Granada, Taunus, Kuga
3  Volvo   V40, V70, 240             V90, S80        V40, V70, 240, V90, S80
```

Comment: What? Just one line of code? ;-) Awesome, it works with the first version. Thank you so much